# How do I change my login/login email?

Tags: support, login

Is there a way to change my login/login email? I could change my email address on the profile description page, but apparently that doesn't change my login email. I see that there's an option on my profile menu bar to add a different login, but apparently when I clicked on the option it doesn't work it only makes me relogin with my old email.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer over on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153555/154443) should help you. In summary:

Use the **My Logins** link on your profile - you can add your new email and remove your old one.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that with no luck. When asked to add a login I clicked the first logo, the Stackexchange logo, but it auto-relogs me in with my old email login instead.

Comment: If it really won't let you add a new one, email team@stackoverflow.com with details.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to change my login e-mail now. This is done through adding a Google account, and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134379/how-can-i-link-two-google-apps-accounts-with-one-so-login) is the instructions from meta.SO.